# PHP - Raplace strings recurively in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

This WORKS:

Example have some dummy arrays: `$query`.

`$query_string_parts` are

```
        foreach ($query as $query_keys => $query_string_parts)
        {
            $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($query_string_parts, ':alpha');

            $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($result['segments']['query'][$query_keys], ':digit');

            $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($result['segments']['query'][$query_keys], ':word');

            $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($result['segments']['query'][$query_keys], ':alphanum');

        }
```

In other way, concern on `BLA`

```
   $bla = somethingfunction($bla, 'case0');
   $bla = somethingfunction($bla, 'case1');
   $bla = somethingfunction($bla, 'case2');
   $bla = somethingfunction($bla, 'case3');
```

This code is mess and not as clean! I don't want like this.

Regex replace is:

`

```
private static $regex_replace = array(':word' => '/^[\w]*$/',
                                      ':digit' => '/^[\d]*$/',
                                      ':alpha' => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/',
                                      ':alphanum' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/'
                                      );


private static function replace_regex_by_key($input, $regex_loop_key)
{
    return preg_replace('/'.$regex_loop_key.'/', static::$regex_replace[$regex_loop_key], $input);
}`
```

RESULT (OKAY!):

BEFORE:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) ":alpha:digit"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "abc"
```

AFTER:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$//^[\d]*$/"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "abc"
```

BUT! A code below is mess and Want to call from arrays from `static::$regex_replace` and change it:

Below code should be less a code and logically, I don't like instead of this:

```
    $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($query_string_parts, ':alpha');

    $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($result['segments']['query'][$query_keys], ':digit');

    $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($result['segments']['query'][$query_keys], ':word');

    $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($result['segments']['query'][$query_keys], ':alphanum');
```

should be like:

```
    foreach (static::$regex_replace as $key) {      
    $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_regex_by_key($query_string_parts, $key);
    }
```

But, it WON'T RECURSIVE RETURNS, maybe using operater `&` but in a class what is best idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*So, after 50 mins and still not answered with 30 times of views, I finally solved this.*

Nevermind, solved as separated function, so I called as:

```
foreach ($query as $query_keys => $query_string_parts)
            {
                $result['segments']['query'][$query_keys] = static::replace_segments($query_string_parts);
            }
```

And function to called as static and executed:

```
private static function replace_segments($results)
{
    foreach (static::$regex_replace as $key => $val)
    {

        $results = static::replace_regex_by_key($results, $key);
    }

    return $results;
}
```